optuna Inconsistent parameters and distributions
I am running real world tests.
I want Optuna to propose me a new set of parameters for my next test.
I am running the code here below in Google Colab :
import optuna
import csv

# Load previous trials from a CSV file
trials = []
with open('trials.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        params = {'param1': float(row[0]), 'param2': float(row[1]), 'param3': float(row[2])}
        value = float(row[3])
        trials.append((params, value))

# Create a new study with the previous trials
study = optuna.create_study(storage='sqlite:///example.db', load_if_exists=True)
for params, value in trials:
    trial = optuna.create_trial(state=optuna.trial.TrialState.COMPLETE, value=value, params=params)
    study.tell(trial)

# Propose a new set of parameters
trial = study.ask()

# Define parameter distributions
param1_distribution = optuna.distributions.UniformDistribution(0, 100)  # Adjust the range as per your requirements
param2_distribution = optuna.distributions.UniformDistribution(0, 100)  # Adjust the range as per your requirements
param3_distribution = optuna.distributions.UniformDistribution(0, 100)  # Adjust the range as per your requirements

param1 = trial.suggest_float('param1', param1_distribution.low, param1_distribution.high)
param2 = trial.suggest_float('param2', param2_distribution.low, param2_distribution.high)
param3 = trial.suggest_float('param3', param3_distribution.low, param3_distribution.high)

print('New params: param1 = {}, param2 = {}, param3 = {}'.format(param1, param2, param3))

with this initial 1 row csv :
20,30,40,-514.960

and gets this error :
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-2-b43d0c0523bf> in <cell line: 15>()
     14 study = optuna.create_study(storage='sqlite:///example.db', load_if_exists=True)
     15 for params, value in trials:
---> 16     trial = optuna.create_trial(state=optuna.trial.TrialState.COMPLETE, value=value, params=params)
     17     study.tell(trial)
     18 

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/optuna/trial/_frozen.py in _validate(self)
    326 
    327         if set(self.params.keys()) != set(self.distributions.keys()):
--> 328             raise ValueError(
    329                 "Inconsistent parameters {} and distributions {}.".format(
    330                     set(self.params.keys()), set(self.distributions.keys())

ValueError: Inconsistent parameters {'param1', 'param3', 'param2'} and distributions set().

It is my very first attempt to use Optuna.
Any help to put me on the right track would be greatly appreciated !

maybe this has fixed the error
# Create a new study with the previous trials
study = optuna.create_study(storage='sqlite:///example.db', load_if_exists=True)
for params, value in trials:
    trial = optuna.trial.create_trial(
        params=params,
        distributions={
            'param1': FloatDistribution(0, 100),
            'param2': FloatDistribution(0, 100),
            'param3': FloatDistribution(0, 100)
        },
        value=value
    )
    study.add_trial(trial)

...
